# Draw bitmap using Metal

Tags: macos, cocoa, metal

Question is quite simple. On Windows you have BitBlt() to draw to the screen. On OS X you could normally use OpenGl but how do I draw the bitmap to the screen using Apples new Metal framework? I cant find anything valuable in Apples Metal references.
I'm right now using Core Graphics for the drawing part but since my bitmap is updating all the time, I feel like I should move to Metal to reduce the overhead.

Comment: this is why we need "lacks minimal understanding" back

Comment: There is no reason you should have to use Metal to draw images. `-[NSImage drawInRect:]` will do just fine.

Comment: Isn't NSImage quite slow compared to Metal? What if I'm updating my bitmap 30 times a second? I asked for Metal because I want to use Metal.

Comment: @user148013 how big is the image that you are updating 30 times a second?

Comment: 500 x 800 pixels. But i could increase the size without problems. I just want to draw to the screen with litte overhead as possible.

Comment: OK, maybe you do need acceleration...

Comment: Can someone tell me how I would handle this? Right know I just have an array that i turn to an image that gets then drawn to the screen. How would I achieve this with metal?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question; I just upvoted it.  I'm not experienced enough to write an answer myself, but a good answer could talk about MTKTextureLoader, about Apple's "Creating and Sampling Textures" sample code, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very short answer is this: First, you need to setup a standard rendering pipeline using Metal, which is a bit of work, if you don't know anything about the rendering pipeline (note: but this can be simplified by avoiding 3D stuff by rendering a quad with two triangles, just give xy coordinates for the vertices). There is a lot of sample code from Apple that shows how to setup a standard rendering pipeline, the simplest is maybe MetalImageProcessing, so you could strip that down (even though that uses a compute shader which is overcomplicated to draw in, you'd want to substitute it for standard vertex and fragment shaders).

Second, you need to learn how vertex and fragment shaders work and how to draw stuff with them, see shadertoy for this.

Just noticed the users last comment, if you have an array of bytes that represent an image then you can just make an MTLTexture out of that and render it to the screen, see Apple's example above but change the compute shader to standard vertex and fragments shaders for faster performance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Would this be faster than using CoreGraphics? Assuming that I'm redrawing the bitmap 60 times a second and that it's quite big and used for fullscreen also. Otherwise I wouldn't need to take this much more complicated path.

Comment: Yes, it will be faster than CoreGraphics when it is setup, you can render a 1080p texture in about 1-3 ms using Metal, so it could easily run at 60fps, but whether it is the way to go depends on multiple factors, mainly concerned with what you are drawing, how you are drawing it, how quickly you can prepare it for the GPU (MTLTexture) or whether you want to draw using shaders (which can be very awkward), in the latter case you basically have x y coordinates and all your drawing has to be pure math, no handy functions that you'd find in CoreGraphics.

Comment: A great question and an answer. I'm thinking to move to Metal (on Mac - there're a few platforms supported in my code) as well, since CG spends a lot of time in what is supposed to be a simple blit on Windows (where it takes ~3ms to blit a 4K image on my machine - an ancient i5 IvyBridge).